# Image of Cantor set under Cantor-Lebesgue function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $m^{\ast}$ be the Lebesgue outer measure and $m$ the Lebesgue measure. Let $\phi$ be the Cantor Lebesgue function and let $\psi(x) := x + \phi(x)$. Let $C$ be the standard Cantor set, why does $m^{\ast}(\psi(C^{c})) = 1$?

I know that: If $I = (a, b)$ is an open interval removed in the construction of the Cantor set, $\psi(I) = I + \phi(a)$ and hence $m^{\ast}(\psi(I)) = m^{\ast}(I) = m(I)$. Since $m(C^{c}) = 1$, $$1 = m\left(\bigcup_{I \in C^{c}}I\right) = \sum_{I \in C^{c}}m(I) = \sum_{I \in C^{c}}m^{\ast}(\psi(I))$$ but the expression on the right hand side is $\geq m^{\ast}(\psi(C^{c}))$ by countable subadditivity of $m^{\ast}$.

Comment: Are you asking about $\phi(C^c)$ or $\psi(C^c)$? I guess it's the latter. I would observe that $C^c$ is the union of disjoint intervals $(a_j,b_j)$, and that $\psi((a_j,b_j))$ is an interval of the same size $b_j-a_j$.

Comment: Ah right, you are indeed correct. Do you know how to now conclude that $m^{\ast}(\psi(C)) = 1$? Of course we have $2 = m^{\ast}([0, 2]) = m^{\ast}(\psi(C) \cup \psi(C^{c})) \leq m^{\ast}(\psi(C)) + 1$, thus it remains to show that $m^{\ast}(\psi(C)) \leq 1$.

Comment: Do you know that open sets are measurable?

Comment: Yes I do know that open sets are measurable.

Comment: So, the image of $C^c$ is open. And the image of $C$ it's compact. You can use the  additivity of measure.